# Recreate table with counts from journals in R and simulate multivariate analysis

Tags: r

I often find the need to recreate tables from manuscripts for further analysis. How can this most easily be accomplished?

For instance:

[image]

Is there an easy way to recreate a dataframe with a total of 4 columns (Cerebral infarct(Y/N), outcome (Poor/good), rebleed(Y/N) and treatment(Nimodipine, placebo) and 276+278 rows so that I can further analyze this?

Edit: As Dwin points out the categories are not mutually exclusive-hence the need for simulating the observed responses

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question - do you want to _simulate_ the raw data from which the summary table was created or do you want to _recreate_ the table from the other manuscript into your own report?

Comment: I want to "simulate" the raw data for the summary table for subsequent further analysis and check of their results

Comment: `?gl` is probably useful here

Comment: Can you edit your question (and title) that will reflect your statement that you need to simulate data?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I really understood what you are up to: recreating the raw data from which the above table was created.

The above table in R (I am not dealing with numbers within parenthesis in the table):

```
tab <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(61, 55, 25, 92, 91, 38), 3, 2))
row.names(tab) <- c('Cerebral infarct', 'Poor outcome', 'Rebleed')
names(tab) <- c('Nimodipine', 'placebo')
```

Which returns in:

```
> tab
                 Nimodipine placebo
Cerebral infarct         61      92
Poor outcome             55      91
Rebleed                  25      38
```

Not the prettiest solution, but easy to follow: I grabbed each cell of the above table and returned a vector of logical values of the needed variables n times and then transformed to data frame:

```
res <- lapply(names(tab), function(col)
    lapply(row.names(tab), function(row)
        rep(c(row=='Cerebral infarct', row=='Poor outcome', row=='Rebleed', col=='Nimodipine'), tab[row, col]) 
))
res <- rapply(res, function(x) x)
res <- as.data.frame(matrix(res, , 4, byrow=T))
names(res) <- c(row.names(tab), names(tab)[1])
```

Result:

```
> str(res)
'data.frame':   362 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Cerebral infarct: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ Poor outcome    : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ Rebleed         : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ Nimodipine      : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

PS: the data frame holds 362 cases as you can see thanks to:

```
> sum(tab)
[1] 362
```

PS: thanks to @DWin's comment I've just realised I did not take care of possible overlaps.

Comment: It would be better to avoid using the name "table" for a data object, since that happens to also be the name of a very useful function. I also have concerns with the statistics. I do not see any indication that these were mutually exclusive outcomes. Surely there was a systematic overlap between these categories. I would have stopped after your first six lines because I consider the next steps unsupported by the data presentation

Comment: the package xtable may also be useful for putting that table into latex format

Comment: Thanks @DWin, you are really right - as usual :) Will leave my answer here anyway with some edits about `table` naming. The sad thing that I did not have in mind the fact that some overlaps might be :( Which makes sense of course too.

Answer (score 0):

As Dwin is pointing out- I did forget about the overlap between the categories.

Here is my take on simulating the dataset and runnning a multivariate analysis based on the numbers reported...Hence after adjusting for the other variables only treatment seems to be related to outcome.

```
treat<-factor(c(rep("Placebo",276),rep("Nimodipine",278)))
infarct<-factor(rep("No",554),levels=c("No","Yes"))
outcome<-factor(rep("Good",554),levels=c("Good","Poor"))
rebleed<-factor(rep("No",554),levels=c("No","Yes"))

df<-data.frame(treat=treat,infarct=infarct,outcome=outcome,rebleed=rebleed)

fun<-function(df){
  d<-df
  nimo<-subset(d,treat=="Nimodipine")
  place<-subset(d,treat=="Placebo")
  nimo$infarct[sample(c(1:278),61)]<-"Yes"
  nimo$outcome[sample(c(1:278),55)]<-"Poor"
  nimo$rebleed[sample(c(1:278),25)]<-"Yes"
  place$infarct[sample(c(1:276),92)]<-"Yes"
  place$outcome[sample(c(1:276),91)]<-"Poor"
  place$rebleed[sample(c(1:276),38)]<-"Yes"
  d<-rbind(nimo,place)
  return(d)
 }

fun2<-function(df){

  glm(outcome~rebleed+infarct+treat,data=df,family=binomial)->f
  exp(coef(f))->f2
 return(f2)
}

lis.data<-list(10000)


for (j in 1:10000){
lis.data[[j]]<-fun(df)  
}

lis.reg<-matrix(NA,10000,4)
for (j in 1:10000){
lis.reg[j,]<-fun2(lis.data[[j]])  
}
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (j in 1:4){
  plot(lis.reg[,j])
}
```

[image]